# Resolve Conflict When Using Highchart and Treemap together ( f.inArray is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, conflict, treemap

```
angular.min.js:2 TypeError: f.inArray is not a function
 at http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/treemap.js:109:31
 at C (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/treemap.js:28:51)
 at Object.j.treemap.o.getListOfParents (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/treemap.js:106:13)
 at Object.j.treemap.o.getTree (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/treemap.js:120:19)
at Object.j.treemap.o.translate (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/treemap.js:379:34)
 at http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/highcharts.js:1:107698
 at Array.forEach (native)
 at each.Array.forEach.g (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/highcharts.js:1:7474)
 at Object.D.renderSeries (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/highcharts.js:1:107670)
    at Object.D.render (http://localhost/ROOT/app/js/highcharts/highcharts.js:1:108560)
```

1. I've traced the problem that the f.inArray function is appear in Treemap.js

Sample code is working properly in JsFiddle but is is not working in my Project

Comment: Since you say that the sample code works on JsFiddle (link?) but not in your project might that be an issue related to file import order?

Comment: JsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/.....file import order is currect

Comment: Please post a live example, e.g. in JSFiddle. For debugging use files with ending .src.js like https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.src.js

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem now.

What version of jQuery are you referencing ? I suspect the issue might be because I'm using jQuery v1.11.3, *inArray* was added in v1.2

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

> jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] ) **version added: 1.2**

Comment: Actually, I was running an older version of Highcharts, *only* upgrading that in itself solved my issue, regardless of the jQuery upgrade. 

My initial setup was running Highcharts v4.1.9. I can confirm treemap is working without issues now in v4.2.4 (current latest)

Comment: This is because you were running an older version of the script ? Please upvote my answer ?